# RewriteRule doesn't work in remote server, when using only one word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I use only one word in RewriteRule, it doesn't work in remote server(It works on local). I couldn't find the problem.
For example; if I use

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L,NC]
```

it doesn't work. But if I use

```
RewriteRule ^about.html$ about.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about.php [L,NC]
```

it works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /.htaccess, you can try this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about$ /about.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^about.html$ /about.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ /about.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works when I added 'Options -MultiViews' into htaccess file.